# How to use 'use-ajax' class with pages created by controller?

Tags: 8, theming, ajax, page-controller

I'm trying to use 'use-ajax' class to load a page inside a modal box.

My Page is dynamically created using node id pass on my page controller

My link looks like this

Any idea on how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a render array that create a link that open a modal windows.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

public function build() {
$output = array();
$output['overlay_link'] = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => $this->t('Add an activity'),
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('node.add', ['node_type' => 'event'], ['query' => ['destination' => $destination],
    'absolute' => TRUE,]),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['use-ajax', 'button', 'secondary'],
    'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
    'data-dialog-options' => \Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json::encode(['title' => t('Add an activity'), 'width' => 800,]),
  ],
);
 return $output;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but if not done elsewhere I think you need to attach the core/drupal.ajax library to the render array?! `$output['overlay_link']['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';`